# self.delegate is ignored when I use delegate, may I ask the reason why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, delegates, sprite-kit

I want to delegate my method through `[self.delegate showShareScreen]` in GameOverScene.m, but I can't delegate that. I would like to know the reason why and solve it.
Working image is that there is a twitter image in Game Over Scene. When I touch it, it will work and twitter share screen will appear and I can use it.

GameOverScene.h

```
#import  <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@protocol sceneDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)showShareScreen;
@end
@interface GameOverScene : SKScene
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <sceneDelegate> delegate;
- (id)init;
@end
```

GameOverScene.m

```
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import "NewGameScene.h"
#import "MainScene.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>

@implementation GameOverScene

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if([node.name isEqualToString:@"twitterbutton"]){
      [self.delegate showShareScreen];
      //When I use the breakpoint, it is ignored.**
   }
 }
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import "GameOverScene.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <sceneDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewGameScene.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import "GameOverScene.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView
{
self.view  = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
GameOverScene *theScene = [[GameOverScene alloc]init];
theScene.delegate = self;
}

-(void)showShareScreen
{ 
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                                composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"TestTweet from the Game !!"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
}

@end
```

Comment: because `note.name` is not `"twitterbutton"`?

Comment: On your breakpoint, output to the console what node.name is, you can use `po [node name]`

Comment: I think yours delegate is not initialized at moment when touch occur. try add `if (nil == self.delegate) NSLog(@"delegate is nil");`

Comment: >>Bryan Chen and Jeff  Yes, node.name is "twitterbutton", right.

Comment: >>Cy-4AH    Thank you for the advice, I did it, and the log shows "delegate is nil" like you indicates. After that, I am so sorry, but may I ask what should I do ?  I am a beginner of Xcode... I think I should initialise self.delegate .